# Calling a managed bean method from JSF

Tags: jsf

I have been through many questions here but doesn't solve my problem. I have an HTML form and I want to call a method of a managed bean class, when the submit button is clicked. Here are the code.

HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action= "" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputUsrname" name="usrname" placeholder="Username" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputUsrname" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <h:commandButton value="click" action="#{hello_World.getMessage()}"/>
    <button class="btn" type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Managed Bean class:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

@ManagedBean(name="hello_World", eager=true)
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Helloworld started from managed bean");
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        System.out.println("sjdfksadfbasdjkfh");
        return "indexx.xhtml";
    }
}
```

When I click the click button, nothing happens. 
Thank you.

Comment: That's because your using an HTML form tag `<form>`. Turn it to JSF specific such as `<h:form>` along with other components like `<h:inputText>`, `<h:outputLabel>`... Also designate your bean using an appropriate scope. Otherwise the default `@RequestScoped` will come into play. `eager=true` is only applicable to application scoped JSF managed beans hereby not CDI managed beans. It is as good as it is removed from the `@ManagedBean`  annotation.

Comment: I didn't get everything you said but yes now I came to know that I need to use JSF specific tags to use the methods. I used `<h:form>` instead of `<form> and it worked.

Comment: The rest is nothing. The default scoped of a JSF managed bean is `@RequestScoped` (from `javax.faces.bean`), it is applied in your case, since you did not mention a scope explicitly and `eager=true` is unnecessary in this case because the bean is not an application scoped JSF managed bean. `eager=true` is only applicable to application scoped JSF managed beans.